# Excel How to stop LEFT formula after meeting first Alpha in string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i am trying to extract just a specific part of text strings (part numbers) for a vlookup,

I have got a formula that gives me the part number I want for most cases, which stops the LEFT formula after it reaches the last number in the text string. Some of the part numbers have more numbers further in the text string.

I need the formula to return the text string until the last number but to stop once it changes back to Alpha again.
I hope this makes sense I have attached a screenshot to example the issue and my code. If you look in column R and see the FR70YERXX/3, that should stop before the Y but i simply can't get my head round this one.[image: Excel Find formula issue]

```
=LEFT(J2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},J2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(J2)))),0)))
```

Comment: It's because it also finds the 3 and you asked for the MAX, which returns the position of the 3 as it is the furthest number.

Comment: I can't figure the formula out to stop searching once the text string changes back to a Letter, I understand why that problem happens, i just can't get my head round how to fix it. I think this one might not be possible to fix with the formula i am currently using

Comment: I think you need VBA

Comment: Would be easiest with a regular expression, they take a while to get used to but websites like [this](http://regexlib.com/(X(1)A(c00YqQQKgbcJLyV3G5pMdubkPBtMIQJBhwSuCPKsAeFmcbzHyq2hNvVKZ9n0bcQ8gfA7chF7Qs_sIFsJ0Z2dFTQMb6hWimXKiyYLgNnQgejDug5KvDFrnXhdAxRFo0o0qRuWg6mbLoWIKUgjX-uDh8bE917XfclNbRq82B_Mx76inHOjpFmDruOION0DSvTG0))/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) are a good place for help with the syntax and [this](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) is a good place to check that the regular expression is working as expected.

Comment: I'll provide a RegEx answer after work if it's still not been done

Comment: I have looked at Regular expressions before but i never put it into practice so i often forget it. is it worth learning or will it not be used much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following code into a module in Excel

```
Function LeftCode(s As String) As String
i = 1
While Not ((Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0") And (Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9")) And (i <= Len(s))
    i = i + 1
Wend
If i > Len(s) Then
    LeftCode = s
Else
    While Not ((Mid(s, i, 1) < "0") Or (Mid(s, i, 1) > "9")) And (i <= Len(s))
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    If i > Len(s) Then
        LeftCode = s
    Else
        LeftCode = Left(s, i - 1)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Then in column R type:

```
=LeftCode(J2)
```

and copy this down

[image: Results]

**Explanation**

**Create a function to take a string and return a string**

```
Function LeftCode(s As String) As String
```

**Starting at the first character, loop through the string one character at a time until you find a digit (0-9)**

```
i = 1
While Not ((Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0") And (Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9")) And (i <= Len(s))
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

**If we have reached the end, with no numbers, then return it all**

```
If i > Len(s) Then
    LeftCode = s
```

**Otherwise continue to loop through each character until we find a non digit**

```
Else
    While Not ((Mid(s, i, 1) < "0") Or (Mid(s, i, 1) > "9")) And (i <= Len(s))
        i = i + 1
    Wend
```

**If we reach the end then we want the whole thing**

```
    If i > Len(s) Then
        LeftCode = s
    Else
```

**Otherwise we want up to the last but one character**

```
        LeftCode = Left(s, i - 1)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I use VBA, but this still went over my head a bit. So I learn, what exactly is happening in this code?

Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: I'm on a train at the moment so can't give you decent feedback. When I get back, I'll comment the code for you.

Comment: I've added some explanation of the code, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to to truncate until the first combination of *digit is followed by non-digit*. If so try this:

```
=LEFT(H2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$98)
 /ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(H2,ROW($1:$98),1)))
 /ISERROR(VALUE(MID(H2,ROW($2:$99),1))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: nice concept.  I think you still need to strip off the leading ab in your example which may not always be 2 characters

Comment: This also worked really well. However the syntax confused me a bit? why in ROW is it just referencing $1:$98? Thank you, good way to solve the problem i will need to research aggregate as i have never used it before

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Well I can give a long ugly looking formula if you are willing to use. Try this

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1))))))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

### Solution 2

Using helper column

In `Cell B2` enter the following formula to get the position of first number

```
=MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789"))
```

Then in `Cell C2` to get the string after removing alphabets preceding first number, enter

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-B2+1)
```

Finally, in `Cell D2` enter the below formula

```
=IFERROR(-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(C2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C2))))),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: This was helpful, i think normally i would have created multiple columns to do something similar to this but i think i couldn't see the wood for the trees.